# Torque : pbs_Server No such file or directory (2) in recov_attr, read2

Tags: pbs, torque

I try to start pbs_server deamon and I get this message :

```
05/30/2016 10:26:57;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::No such file or directory (2) in recov_attr, read2
05/30/2016 10:26:57;0001;PBS_Server;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::que_recov, recov_attr[common] failed
```

pbs deamon appear to be running

```
root      4670     1  0 10:27 ?        00:00:40 /usr/local/sbin/pbs_server -d /var/torque
```

but jobs are stuck

Do you have any idea about the pb ?

Thank you very much for the help
Vince

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a problem with your queues, possibly file corruption. I would check the files in `server_priv/queues`. If you have a new enough version, the files will be in XML format, in which case you can manually revise them. If you have doubts about any of them, you can just move them out of the way, but if you have jobs running in any queue the server cannot find when it loads up, you may lose those jobs.

Comment: Thank you very much clusterdure :)  
Indeed there was a text file in `server_priv/queues` directory, generated by a script, who caused this problem. I deleted this "bad" file, restarted torque and It's working –

Comment: Please be sure to upvote as useful and accept the answer as the best one (albeit the only one - heh heh) so that it credits my stackoverflow reputation. Thanks!